# Language and currency switcher js error

Tags: javascript, magento2.3, currency, multicurrency, language-switcher

Added language and currency switcher to template using this below layout.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.settings" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Settings</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store.settings.language" template="Magento_Store::switch/languages.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="id_modifier" xsi:type="string">nav</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Directory\Block\Currency" name="store.settings.currency" template="Magento_Directory::currency.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="id_modifier" xsi:type="string">nav</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
```

But When I click on dropdown there shows this below error

> TypeError: event.target.matches is not a function

This is multistore concept.

Comment: Have you recompiled or redeployed your static content?

Comment: I have upgraded, compiled and deployed but no use